# AWS VPC failed communicating through VPN Tunnel

Tags: vpn, amazon-web-services, ipsec, amazon-vpc, site-to-site-vpn

I have created a VPC scenario 3 in AWS. Configured ipsec vpn site to site between aws and cyberoam. Tunnels are up. I have added the security groups to the ec2 instance in private subnet to give full access to anyone in VPC. Still i am not able to ping to the private ec2 instance from my laptop which is connected to local/private network of cyberoam. In aws we have written static routes to private subnet. Indicating to route packets from private subnet to virtual private gateway(i.e 0.0.0.0/0 to virtual private gateway). As per tracepath the packets doesnt pass virtual private gateway. Also the generic configuration file that i downloaded from VPN connection contains "Inside IP address" is this to be added to security group or in cyberoam firewall?